# Merging a changelist into another stream - 'Change ###### already committed.'

Tags: perforce

I'm using the following p4 command to merge from one stream into another:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=targetstreamclient_XYZ

p4 merge -c 123456 -n --from Main
```

When I execute this, I keep getting the message 'Change ###### already committed.' This cannot be since the change list has definitely not been merged into the other workspace/stream.
I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-c` flag is for specifying the *pending* changelist that you want to open the files in (i.e. the changelist that will become the *target* of the merge).  It sounds like you want to specify the *source* of the merge, which is a changelist that is already committed (by default this is the latest changelist).  Do:

```
p4 merge -n --from Main @123456
```

to (preview) merge everything from `Main` up to change `123456`.  If you want to cherry-pick change `123456` without any of the preceding changes, do:

```
p4 merge -n --from Main @123456,@123456
```

If `-c` is not specified, the files are opened in the "default" changelist (i.e. no changelist at all; the files will be moved to a numbered changelist automatically when you submit).